# Image Icon output from server outputting on second client connect

Tags: java, image, sockets, server, client

I am experiencing a problem when trying to output an image from a simple server application to a client. When client number one attempts to connect, an error is thrown stating that they are unable to connect and the following error is displayed:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at ClientHandler.run(AuctionServer.java:456)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1576)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
    at AuctionServer.main(AuctionServer.java:71)
```

I believe that this is caused during the object output and receiving through the client, but I am unsure. I have provided lines of code I believe that are relevant:

Server side:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args)
                            throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket client = null;
        final ClientHandler handler = null;
        Scanner getCurrentTime;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (final IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPort unavailable");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe server connection has been established\n");

        String timeNow = null;
        getCurrentTime = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nPlease set the end time for Item1");
        timeNow = getCurrentTime.nextLine();
        final Auction itemOne = new Auction("123456", "Gold watch",timeNow,
                "Antique watch, gold as new");

        System.out.println("\nPlease set the end time for Item2");
        timeNow = getCurrentTime.nextLine();
        final Auction itemTwo = new Auction("223344", "Football ticket",timeNow,
                "1966 World Cup Final Signed Ticket");

        itemOne.start();
        itemTwo.start();


        final Users user = new Users(itemOne,itemTwo);
        final ArrayList<ClientHandler> users =
                                new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();
        final ArrayList<String> bidders = 
                                new ArrayList<String>();


        do
        {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
            bidders.add(getCurrentTime.nextLine());
            bidders.add(client.getInetAddress().toString());
            Bidder bidder = new Bidder(bidders);
            System.out.println("\nUser" + (user.getNumOfUsers()+1)
                                            + " has been accepted to the auction system.\n");
            user.incUsers(users, client, handler);
            System.out.println(bidder.returnUsers());
            //maybe insert a try block
            try
            {

            ObjectOutputStream outStream =
                    new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            outStream.writeObject(new ImageIcon("beesting.jpg"));

            outStream.flush();
            }
            catch(IOException ioEx)
            {
                ioEx.printStackTrace();
            }

        }while (true);
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
private static void sendMessages()
{
    String serverResponse;

    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(host,PORT);
        netOutput = new PrintWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        netInput = new Scanner (socket.getInputStream());
        serverResponse = netInput.nextLine();
        itemArray[0]=messageReceived(0,serverResponse);
        itemArray[1]=messageReceived(2,serverResponse);
        comboBox.addItem(itemArray[0]);     //Adds items to drop down.
        comboBox.addItem(itemArray[1]);
        comboBox.removeItemAt(0);
        comboBox.removeItemAt(0);
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine()); //edits the text area to show bids etc.
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine());
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine());
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine());
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine());
        itemInformation.append("\n" + netInput.nextLine());

        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        image = (ImageIcon)inStream.readObject();

    }
    catch(final IOException ioEx)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Sorry we couldn't connect you! Please try again.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfEx)
    {
        cnfEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    JImage.setIcon(image);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can just change input streams... might be wrong on this though. `netInput = new Scanner (socket.getInputStream());` and then later on you do `ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`

Comment: so, how could I then pass an object through an input stream without creating a new instance of one?

Comment: i do believe you can but i think you must close the `scanner` one first? or worst comes the worst just use `ObjectInputStream` for all of it. Since `Strings` are `Serializable`

Comment: Can you provide an answer for this because I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: Well i see your problem now in your server class you have `getCurrentTime = new Scanner(System.in);` but you don't `close` it and reassign it? its still linked to the `System.in` so you need to reassign to the clients input stream

Comment: Okay well I dont really understand, can youput an answer with the code on if possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109584/discussion-between-davedavidson-and-3kings).